# API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator when trying to access child context property

Tags: ios, core-data

On the following code:

```
CustomObject *customObject = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithContext:self.persistentContainer.viewContext];
customObject.name = @"TEST";
customObject.customID = 1234;

NSManagedObjectContext *firstContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
firstContext.parentContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
CustomObject *contextObj = [firstContext objectWithID:customObject.objectID];
NSError *error;

[self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:&error];
NSLog(@"ERROR [%@", error);
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
```

I get the result:

```
ERROR [(null)
[error] error:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x6000015fa300, store PSC = 0x0)
CoreData: error:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x6000015fa300, store PSC = 0x0)
NAME [(null)]
```

I'm trying to understand why this warning is appearing. I'd expect that after saving the main context I'd still be able to access a property on an object on its child context without any issues.

The interesting part is that if I unfault the contextObj before the save on the main context, everything works fine:

```
CustomObject *customObject = [[CustomObject alloc] initWithContext:self.persistentContainer.viewContext];
customObject.name = @"TEST";
customObject.customID = 12234;

NSManagedObjectContext *firstContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType];
firstContext.parentContext = self.persistentContainer.viewContext;
CustomObject *contextObj = [firstContext objectWithID:customObject.objectID];
NSError *error;
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);
[self.persistentContainer.viewContext save:&error];
NSLog(@"ERROR [%@", error);
NSLog(@"NAME [%@]", contextObj.name);

NAME [TEST]
ERROR [(null)
NAME [TEST]
```

Any ideas on why this is happening would be appreciated.
Thanks.