# Core Data is giving an error, even though I am not using Core Data in my project

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

Can someone explain why these errors keep coming up?
I have gotten rid of all traces of Core Data from the project, yet it keeps coming up.
These errors go away if I add the Assets folder to Development Assets, but I don’t want to do that for obvious reasons…

The error:

```
/Users/{user}/Documents/GitHub/ZoZo/CoreData error build:  API Misuse: Attempt to serialize store access on non-owning coordinator (PSC = 0x600000a0d8f0, store PSC = 0x0)
```

The /ZoZo/CoreData/ folder does not even exist, which is even more confusing...

This error only shows up when Archiving the project, not when building it normally

Comment: Sounds very similar to some of the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559944/coredata-error-api-misuse-attempt-to-serialize-store-access-on-non-owning-coor

Comment: I would first expect that you're using a third-party library that uses Core Data. Turn on `com.apple.CoreData.ConcurrencyDebug` as described in jrturton's linked post, and hopefully it will crash the program in Debug with a stack trace when it makes a mistake.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I was not using any library that was using CoreData. Turns out, it talked about Xcode's internal use of CoreData. Using the new single-image iconset in Xcode 14 alongside older Xcode 13 iconsets is what causes this issue, I had to revert to the old icons to get it to function